# Mailcore: Using syncMessagesWithFolder

Tags: ios, objective-c, mailcore2

I have an array of UIDs I want to sync with the folder. The UIDS argument in the method takes an MCOIndexSet. I'm not sure how I can pass my specific list of UIDS in that manner.

In other words how do I convert my array of UIDS to an MCOIndexSet?

Comment: create a new MCOIndexSet and use -addIndex: to add each uid.

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà Thanks! I wasn't aware of that method - I should have checked the source more carefully.

Comment: @kmcgrady just a side question since we seem to be working on similar problem. In the documentation:

warn Important: This is only for servers that support Conditional Store. See RFC4551 vanishedMessages will be set only for servers that support QRESYNC. See RFC5162
_____

May I ask if you working with gmail? AFAIK gmail does not support QRESYNC. how do you plan to check for vanished messages then?

Comment: @iamdavidlam I'm working with lots of servers but I have noticed that Gmail doesn't seem to be returning anything for vanished messages. I don't have a solution yet unfortunately. I guess a possible one would be doing a fetch operation on all messages and comparing with your local store. Not ideal but as long as you don't pull structures or anything the fetch operation should be pretty quick.